# Validation issues with HTML tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

The database saves the HTML tags from the input form and I would like to strip them to do correct validation. I tested the below method in IRB and it seems to work fine. However I cannot figure out how to use this method to do my validation.

Here's the code from my model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates strip_tag(:text), length: {minimum: 3}, uniqueness: true
  
  def strip_tag(record)
    record.split(/\<.*?\>/).map(&:strip).reject(&:empty?).join(' ').gsub(/\s,/,',')
  end
end
```

The issue I am facing is that  am checking for uniqueness and the length to be greater than 3, but because of the HTML tags it's easy to create duplicates for example.

Example of a duplication after remove tags:

```
"<p><span style=\"color: #1d3d70; font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'; font-size: 16px; background-color: #ffffff;\">Testing 8449</span></p>"
```

and this one:

```
"<p>Testing 8449</p>"
```

Both should have the same values after removing the HTML tags and I want to prevent this duplicates for example.

Comment: Why not use [`ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper#strip_tags`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags) instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: `strip_tags` is the way to go. But is there a business reason that you have to store the HTML tags in that field? Validating uniqueness in this way is likely to cause pain and suffering in the future. An alternate approach would be to store the result of `strip_tags` in another field and perform validation on that field instead.

Comment: I'll use trip_tag instead. @ryan I am storing the tags because the user wants a rich format text. They can change the fonts, create tables, insert hyperlinks, use paragraphs, etc ... Like they can do in Word

Answer (score 0):

i think you need another column such as `check_sum` of the striped tags text and validate uniqueness that column, so on `before_validation` callback you strip tags then calculate and set `check_sum` of the striped tags text.

```rb
# migration add new column check_sum
t.string   :checksum,     null: false

# model
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :striped_text

  before_validation :check_sum_pure_text

  validates :striped_text, length: {minimum: 3}
  validates_uniqueness_of :checksum
  
  def strip_tag(record)
   # ... 
  end

  def check_sum_pure_text
   self.striped_text = strip_tag(rich_text)
   # NOTE about case_sensitive
   # 'user' == 'User' ???
   self.checksum = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.striped_text)
  end
end
```

Note: the reason why you need one more column `checksum` is about performance, pre-calculating `checksum` column will help to speed-up the checking uniqueness validation.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up striping html tags to the value. I got a collection from the database of the column I wanted to check to see if it's unique and stripping the html tags from there. I used the value to see if the collection from the database contained the value. I couldn't figure out how to strip the tags during the database query.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  
  validate :check_duplicates

  private

  def check_duplicates
    strip_txt = ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(text)
    errors.add(
      :text, 
      'Text already stored. Text must be unique'
    ) if (
       Task.select('text')
       .pluck(:text)
       .collect{|e|ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(e)}.include? strip_txt)
   end
end
```